# Get the details of latest transaction details of all employees based on selected transaction type

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb, procedural-programming

everyone. Some one who can help me to get the latest transaction details of employees based on selected transaction type.
Below is the sample tables.

employees Table:

| employee_id | employee_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Doe |
| 2 | Jane Doe |
| 3 | Teri Dactyl |
| 4 | Allie Grater |

transactions Table:

| transaction_id | employee_id | transaction_date | transaction_type | remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-03-28 | Add | test 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-09-07 | Add | test 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 2019-08-01 | Add | test 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 2023-06-05 | Read | test 4 |
| 5 | 4 | 2023-05-12 | Add | test 5 |
| 6 | 2 | 2020-02-01 | Read | test 6 |
| 7 | 3 | 2022-11-15 | Update | test 7 |
| 8 | 1 | 2020-06-14 | Add | test 8 |
| 9 | 1 | 2020-01-14 | Update | test 9 |
| 10 | 2 | 2023-12-31 | Delete | test 10 |

Then now, I want to get list of employees and their latest transaction details where transaction_type is either [Add, Update, Read]

Below is my desired output:

| Transaction ID | Employee Name | Transaction Date | Transaction Type | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Allie Grater | 2023-06-05 | Read | test 4 |
| 7 | Teri Dactyl | 2022-11-15 | Update | test 7 |
| 1 | John Doe | 2021-03-28 | Add | test 1 |

As you can see, Jane Doe is not in the list, because her last transaction type is Delete which is not in the selected transaction type [Add, Update, Read]

Below is my Code:

```
<?php

$transaction_types = ['Add', 'Update', 'Read'];

$output = '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM transactions 
          INNER JOIN employees ON employees.employee_id = transactions.employee_id 
          WHERE transactions.transaction_type IN ('".implode("', '", $transaction_types)."') 
          GROUP BY transactions.employee_id 
          ORDER BY DATE(transactions.transaction_date) DESC
          ";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
   if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
      $output .= '<table>
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th>Transaction ID</th>
                          <th>Employee Name</th>
                          <th>Transaction Date</th>
                          <th>Transaction Type</th>
                          <th>Remarks</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
      foreach ($result as $row) {
         $output .= '<tr>
                        <td>'.$row->transaction_id.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->employee_name.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->transaction_date.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->transaction_type.'</td>
                        <td>'.$row->remarks.'</td>
                     </tr>';
      }
      $output .= '</tbody></table>';
   }
}

echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: You code should generate the error: _"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'Add'"_, did you notice that? See: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) The array should probably be: `['Add', 'Update', 'Read']`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks already updated but my major concern is the sql statement on how to get my desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first have to remove the users with `Delete` from your results set and then use the `row_number()` window function with CTE to select the max dates

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT t.transaction_id AS transaction_id
        ,t.transaction_date AS transaction_date
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY e.employee_name ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC
            ) AS rn
        ,e.employee_name AS employee_name
        ,t.transaction_type AS transaction_type
        ,t.remarks AS remarks
    FROM employees e
    JOIN transactions t ON t.employee_id = e.employee_id
    WHERE e.employee_name NOT IN (
            SELECT e.employee_name
            FROM employees e
            JOIN transactions t ON t.employee_id = e.employee_id
            WHERE transaction_type = 'Delete'
            )
    )
SELECT cte.transaction_id
    ,cte.transaction_date
    ,cte.employee_name
    ,cte.transaction_type
    ,cte.remarks
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/gxfy5VEX) here

Comment: Thanks @zhiguang, but do you have a simple answer that output the same?

Comment: there might be a more concise and elegant way to do it but what i posted is my only solution